# Incorrect display of data from two combined queries

Tags: mysql, sql

I have two tables: Employees and Clients.
I wanted to make a query from two tables that do not have any relations, but for some reason the data is not displayed correctly.

worker:

[image]

users:

[image]

The Employees table doesn't have an employee with this type of data, and the Users table does, but I don't understand why the worker field appears in the results instead of the user field

[image]

Comment: that's how unions work, right? it merges second query result into first query result. even if there's no data in first query result, it will have the column name as worker(first query's column name).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From the [MySQL documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/union.html) (emphasis added):

> UNION combines the result from multiple SELECT statements into a single result set. **The result set column names are taken from the column names of the first SELECT statement.**

Your query is behaving as expected.

Answer (score 1):

Alternative :

```
SELECT worker.worker_id as worker, users.user_id as client 
FROM worker,internet_magazine.users WHERE
worker.email='example@emai.ru' AND users.email='example@emai.ru'
```